# Printing multiple file types using java

Tags: java, printing

Hey i was wondering if there is a specific api for printing a bunch of common file types(pdf,doc,docx,txt, etc..). I am trying to develop program similar to HP's eprint. eprint annoys me because it prints an email as well as the file attached to it. I just want something i can send files directly to. I have found that java has a printing api, but that seems to focus on printing something from a gui window. any ideas much appreciated!

Thanks

Morpheous

Answer (score 3):

It would be difficult for Java alone to be able to print a variety of different file types, and most of the time I've seen Java programs use other programs to do the printing by using Runtime.exec.  If you're going to be trying to use this though, please be sure to read this extremely important article: [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html)

Comment: could a different language be used like c++?

Comment: That's not the problem as you'll have the same issue with C/C++. The problem is that printing is usually handled by the application that creates the file, for instance MS Word for .doc files especially if you are trying to print multiple file types, and so if you want to print multiple file types, you'll often want to tell the app (such as Ms Word) to print the file.  This can often be done in Java via the Runtime.exe.