# Create a virtual printer in Java

Tags: java, printing

I would like to create a virtual printer using Java, so that when you go to print a file( using Word or something) the Java printer is listed as a valid printer.  My goal is to get the printer formatted object that the programs (Word, etc..) send directly to the printer. I don't know if this is possible. It seemed like a more logical solution to this question:

[Printing multiple file types using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300160/printing-multiple-file-types-using-java)

Any ideas?  I heard this is only possible using C or C++, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [LPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_Printer_Daemon_protocol) implementation available in Java.  You can then create manually a printer in Windows which use the LPR protocol to print to said Java LPD.  This captures the result as a byte stream which you can then manipulate further.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like exactly what i need :)

Comment: @thorbjorn-ravn-andersen Hi.. I went through the lpdspooler lib.. but can it handle all kinds of data ? like images ? other documents ? or just plain text ?

Comment: @dreamer Lpd just receives a byte stream intended for a printer.  It is the printer drivers responsibility to generate that byte stream.

Comment: I couldn't find the Java version of this code from the above link.  But I was able to download it from here:  http://freecode.com/projects/lpdspooler

Answer (score 3):

You will have to write [a new printer driver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_printer) that [re-direct API calls to your Java classes](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/730502.html).

Answer (score 0):

**RedMon**

You could use [RedMon](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/redmon/en/redmon.htm) to pipe the printed output into a Java program. Together with a Standard postscript driver this would give you Postscript that can be read and post-processed by your Java program.

> The RedMon port monitor redirects a special printer port to a program.
>   RedMon is commonly used with Ghostscript and a non-PostScript printer
>   to emulate a PostScript printer.
>
> RedMon **can be used with any program** that accepts data on standard
>   input.